# How to save Map Overlay and Current Map-Center on Screen Orientation in Android?

Tags: android, maps

I am trying to create a map activity with an overlay image on the user location. Currently, I can maintain the map state when the screen is rotated by returning mapV.getMapCenter() in onRetainNonConfigurationInstance.

But how can I save both the map state and the user location (Overlay image) when the screen is rotated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User a holder object.

```
private class Holder{
    public Overlay image;
    public GeoPoint center;

    public Holder(Overlay image, GeoPoint center){
        this.image = image;
        this.center = center;
    }
}

@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return new Holder(image, center);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Holder holder = (Holder) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    if (holder != null) {
            overlay = new ItemOverlay();
            overlay.setFocus(holder.overlay.getFocus());

            mapOverlays.add(overlay);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is the holder object class to be used inside the onCreate() method or in the main Activity scope?

Comment: Unfortunately no..to backtrack, i would like to save the user-location(GeoPoint) as well as overlays when the screen is rotated i.e if the screen is rotated if the image was on Chicago, then after rotation the image should still show up on Chicago. Currently it only redraws the map to the GeoPoint without the image overlay.

Comment: @Faisal you will have to reconstruct the overlay. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately my app crashes when I try this. Maybe I'm doing something wrong! :(

Comment: Sbossb, do you have any idea on the "setRetainInstance" method? If yes,do you think it can help me in the current issue?

Comment: Thank You @Sbossb for your help. I finally got it working. I had to declare the user geo-point to be global. Seems so obviuos now! :)

Comment: 'setRetainInstance()' is the latest and greatest version of 'onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()' it is only included in the new version of Android. You will need to use the compatibility pack inorder to access those methods

Comment: @Faisal great! I hope I was able to help

Comment: Yes, @Sbossb you were a BIG HELP! Your answers really guided me in the right direction. Thank you so much fellow Androider! :) (Android Developer)